# Is it possible to check if a given Matlab script is run by itself or called by another script?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, call

I have a Matlab script A that can either be run by itself or be called by another script. I want to enter an `if` statement in script A that checks if the script is run by itself or called by another script. How can I check this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check out [`dbstack`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html).

> `dbstack` displays the line numbers and file names of the function calls that led to the current breakpoint, listed in the order in which they were executed. The display lists the line number of the most recently executed function call (at which the current breakpoint occurred) first, followed by its calling function, which is followed by its calling function, and so on.

And:

> In addition to using dbstack while debugging, you can also use dbstack within a MATLAB code file outside the context of debugging. In this case, to get and analyze information about the current file stack. For example, to get the name of the calling file, use dbstack with an output argument within the file being called. For example:
>
> `st=dbstack;`

The following is stolen from the `iscaller` function posted on the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13164-iscaller/content//iscaller.m).

```
function valOut=iscaller(varargin)
stack=dbstack;
%stack(1).name is this function
%stack(2).name is the called function
%stack(3).name is the caller function
if length(stack)>=3
    callerFunction=stack(3).name;
else
    callerFunction='';
end
if nargin==0
    valOut=callerFunction;
elseif iscellstr(varargin)
    valOut=ismember(callerFunction,varargin);
else
    error('All input arguments must be a string.')
end    
end
```

<sub>Credit for this approach goes to [Eduard van der Zwan](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/409119-eduard-van-der-zwan).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function [`dbstack` - Function call stack](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html).

Let's add this to the beginning of your script file, call it 'dbstack_test.m':

```
% beginning of script file
callstack = dbstack('-completenames');
if( isstruct( callstack ) && numel( callstack ) >= 1 )
    callstack_mostrecent = callstack(end); % first function call is last
    current_file = mfilename('fullpath'); % get name of current script file
    current_file = [current_file '.m']; % add filename extension '.m'

    if( strcmp( callstack_mostrecent.file, current_file ) )
        display('Called from itself');
    else
        display( ['Called from somewhere else: ' callstack_mostrecent.file ] );
    end
else
    warning 'No function call stack available';
end
```

Add a second script called 'dbstack_caller_test' to call your script:

```
run dbstack_test
```

Now when you run `dbstack_test` from the console or click the green triangle in your MATLAB editor:

```
>> dbstack_test
Called from itself
```

When you call it running from `dbstack_caller_test`

```
>> dbstack_caller_test
Called from somewhere else: /home/matthias/MATLAB/dbstack_caller_test.m
```

When you call it within MATLAB's editor using "run current section" (Ctrl+Return) you get

```
Warning: No function call stack available
```

Of course you can modify the code dependent on which level you are required to use from the call stack.

As already mentioned in the documentation: "In addition to using dbstack while debugging, you can also use dbstack within a MATLAB code file outside the context of debugging."